# How to get a Trackable Hit with Raycast from Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm using ARCore 1.5.  I'm able to use touch to get a Frame.Raycast to place an object (based on the HelloAR scene that ships with ARCore).  I've modified the Prefab and the code to add a Mesh Collider to the generated plane(s).  While this works to get a Physics.Raycast hit from the center of camera, I cannot seem to add an ARCore Anchor at that point because I don't seem to have a Vector3 value from that hit.

In the most general terms, I'd like to do a Raycast from the center of camera to the ARCore generated plane/mesh and add a GameObject.  Does anyone have any solution for this?

EDIT. Here's what I have that is working:

```
TrackableHit hitTouch;
TrackableHitFlags raycastFilter = TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon | 
TrackableHitFlags.FeaturePointWithSurfaceNormal;

if (Frame.Raycast(FirstPersonCamera.transform.position, FirstPersonCamera.transform.forward, out hitTouch, 100f, raycastFilter))
{
    //Instantiate Prefab at the hit pose.
    hitPlaneAddedObject = Instantiate(AddToPlanePrefab, hitTouch.Pose.position, hitTouch.Pose.rotation);

    //Make an ARCore Anchor at the hit pose.
    var anchor = hitTouch.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hitTouch.Pose);

    // Make prefab a child of the anchor.
    hitPlaneAddedObject.transform.parent = anchor.transform;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Why do you need `Physics.Raycast` ? Cant you use `Frame.Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, out TrackableHit hitResult, float maxDistance, TrackableHitFlags filter)`?

Comment: Thanks @AliKanat I did get it working.  Had to add an ARCore anchor properly.